# Pandas: use str.contains with a lot of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` and I need to use `str.contains`, but I have a lot of condition and there are in `df1`.
I try

`df2[df2['url'].str.contains[df3['buys']]]` but it returns

`TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`
What's wrong?

`df2` looks like

```
                                                     url                  used_at  \
0      eldorado.ru/personal/order.php?step=confirm&Cu...  2016-04-01 00:16:46   
1      eldorado.ru/personal/order.php?step=confirm&Cu...  2016-04-01 00:19:56   
2      shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-01 00:29:17   
3      shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-01 00:29:43   
4      icashier.alipay.com/payment/payment-result.htm...  2016-04-01 00:30:11   
5      shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...  2016-04-01 00:31:11   
6      icashier.alipay.com/payment/payment-result.htm...  2016-04-01 00:31:27   
7                  kupivip.ru/shop/checkout/confirmation  2016-04-01 00:49:13   
8                  kupivip.ru/shop/checkout/confirmation  2016-04-01 00:49:37   
9      lk.wildberries.ru/basket/orderconfirmed?orderI...  2016-04-01 01:25:25
```

`df3` looks like

```
buy
shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_order
ozon.ru?context=order_done
lk.wildberries.ru/basket/orderconfirmed
lamoda.ru/checkout/onepage/success/quick
mvideo.ru/homeshop/order.php
eldorado.ru/personal/order.php?step=confirm
ulmart.ru/checkout/confirm
checkout.payments.ebay.com/*pagename=success
svyaznoy.ru/cart/order/created
```

Comment: `contains` is a method, proper usage is `contains(df3['buy'])`

Comment: @sirfz it returns `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
`

Comment: You have a different problem now so please update your question to reflect that. I believe what you need here is `df2['url'].str in df3['buys']`

Comment: So you have duff data anywhere here? does `df2[df2['url'].dropna().str.contains('|'.join(df3['buys'].dropna()))]` work? or do you need to convert any missing values to 'nan' first? e.g. `df2['url'] = df['url'].astype(str)` and `df3['buy'] = df3['buy'].astype(str)`

Comment: `df2[df2['url'].dropna().str.contains('|'.join(df3['buys'].dropna()))]` return `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`

Comment: @piRSquared it's column with `buy`

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis:

```
df2[df2['url'].str.contains(df3['buys'])]
```

the error

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

is saying that you are using square brackets after an object that doesn't know what to do with the square brackets.

When you use square brackets, python calls a method `__getitem__` on the object with the square brackets.  In this case, `str.contains[]`.  You should be calling it with parenthesis `str.contains()`.

#### Problem 2

This should help get you where you need.  Keep in mind, you may need to tweak this still.  And, this is super hacky.

```
matches = pd.DataFrame([], df2.url, df3.buy).apply(lambda x: x.index.str.contains(x.name)).stack()
matches[matches].index.levels[0]

Index([u'eldorado.ru/personal/order.php?step=confirm&Cu...',
       u'icashier.alipay.com/payment/payment-result.htm...',
       u'kupivip.ru/shop/checkout/confirmation',
       u'lk.wildberries.ru/basket/orderconfirmed?orderI...',
       u'shoppingcart.aliexpress.com/order/confirm_orde...'],
      dtype='object', name=u'url')
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @that's the error you get after you fixed the first thing.

Comment: We can't really help further without more detail.  I've told you what was wrong and what that error message was.  You should provide sample data and what you expect if you want more.  You might want to consider asking a separate question as that will fundamentally change what this question was asking.

Comment: @ldevyataykina or try EdChum's suggestion and if that works, call it good.

Comment: I add a part of my `df`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can pass a regex that joins the contents:

```
In [180]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hello','world','python']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hello','johnny']})
df[df['a'].str.contains('|'.join(df1['a']))]

Out[180]:
       a
0  hello
```

So in your case:

```
df2[df2['url'].str.contains('|'.join(df3['buys']))]
```

should work

Here I show the result of the `join`:

```
In [182]:
'|'.join(df1['a'])

Out[182]:
'hello|johnny'
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: Now `TypeError: sequence item 13: expected string or Unicode, float found`

Comment: Well you have duff values in your `df3['buys']` column then, try `df2[df2['url'].str.contains('|'.join(df3['buys'].dropna()))]`

Comment: I add a part of my `df`